# Floating four figures tightly around eachothers borders

Tags: floats, floating

I'm trying to minimise the amount of cutting for printing daily memes on my office door.

Restricting the size is only necessary with regards to the width of the figures and I'm okay with half the usable space of half a `\usepackage{fullpage}` width.

This is what I've got so far, also using the `subcaption` package:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{image1.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{image2.png}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{image3.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{image4.png}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Which renders the following document: 
[image: document-example-memes-floating]

I imagine an equivalent to `\vfill` or similar could be useful. Do note that there's a slight gap between each figure's horizontal neighbour - I'd like to remove this as well.

Comment: you don't want these images to automatically float to another page, so you can remove the figure and subfigure environments and just use `\includegraphics`

Comment: the space is the word-space you have between the subfigures, use  no space: `\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}` not  `\end{subfigure} \begin{subfigure}` (if you use `subfigure` at all)